# How can Debug Only my Code in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code

There is a feature in the **Visual Code** to **only debug my code**

Is this feature available in the **Android Studio**?

I using **Flutter**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an option to start in debug mode. See below, the picture attached

You can see the "bug" icon, after "play" icon

Also is hovered in grey colour

[image: Debug button]